# Best practice or workaround for RSpec specs faking class constants

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing, rspec

Let's say I have classes Car and Mechanic. Car has "run" method. Mechanic requires Car for some reason. Then I write RSpec specs. In mechanic I define a fake clas like this:

```
class Car; end
```

and later stub the method that mechanic uses on it. All works fine if I run tests seperately. But when I run both tests together (rspec spec/directory/) my Mechanic specs use real Car class.

So. I guess this is because ruby classes are "open" and I already loaded the class once for Car specs. But is there a better way to do this? What are best practices for this kind of situations? Does this mean my code needs some improvements cause it's probably tightly coupled?

I made a quick demo in github: https://github.com/depy/RspecTest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fake class wont work since Ruby Classes are open.

One approach you could be using is to use [let](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-11/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let) to initialize the objects the way you want, and if needed work with the relationship on a before block. Stubs are welcome as well inside the before blocks. =p

Hope this helps you!

Comment: But sometimes when I require some class that class includes something else. I have to fake that "else" before require. What about that?

Comment: Thats the behavior i told you to do in the before block. Like u can have 2 lets, 1 for each of your classes, and on the before block, u can make a stub to return the other object based on a call on the first.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is two-layer testing:

- unit specs: testing each class in isolation
- integration specs: testing as a whole

Given the code as follows:

```
class Car
end

class Mechanic
  def fix(car)
    # do something here
  end
end
```

For unit specs I would stub the dependencies, for example:

```
describe Mechanic do
  let(:mechanic) { described_class.new }
  let(:car)      { stub(stubbed_method_on_car: 14) } # Or just OpenStruct.new(stubbed_method_on_car: 14)

  it 'does some stuff' do
    mechanic.fix(car).should eq true
  end
end
```

For integration specs I would do this:

```
describe Mechanic do
  let(:mechanic) { FactoryGirl.create(:mechanic) }
  let(:car)      { FactoryGirl.create(:car) }

  it 'does some stuff' do
    mechanic.fix(car).should eq true
  end
end
```

Comment: For the unit specs, could you describe what the blocks for the two `let` methods are doing?

Comment: Hm. The actuall example is that I have NotificationService which has publish method that is invoked by Task instance. And inside NotificationService.publish the Notification object is created and published. I don't want task to know anything about NotificationClass it just knows it can use NotificationService for publishing and the service does all the other stuff. But How do I unit test that and be able to run all the unit tests together not each seperately. I don't want NotificationService to use real Notification class because Notification test laoded it. I hope it made that clear... :)

Comment: @Knownasilya: in short `let` sets an accessor to the instance variable `:mechanic` -> `@mechanic` which is reset after every example to its pristine state

Comment: @MatjazMuhic: do I understand correctly? `Task` uses `NotificationService.publish` internally? If yes, you can just stub this method by `NotificationService.stub(:publish)` or if you are using instance of `NotificationService` it will be: `NotificationService.any_instance.stub(:publish)`. I think you have to provide more clear example so I will be able to help you :)

Comment: Let me put it this way. From my github example. Car specs require a Car class and if I want to create a fake in Mechanic specs I can't cause it somehow uses Car class which Car specs loaded.

Answer (score -1):

Rspec has built in support for [stubbing constants](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-11/docs/stubbing-constants/stub-defined-constant).